# Iterate Python List of Lists and Remove Final Index of Each Sublist, No Imports

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, matrix, list-comprehension

There are a few similar questions to this one but not exactly the same:

I want to dynamically decrease a given input array or list of lists. For example:

```
matrix = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

Starting at 0 I need to iterate through and remove the final index - the iterative. So the output I would like to store in a new list is:

```
#output
[0,1,2], ,[3,4], [6]] 
[0,1,2], ,[3,4], [6]] ==> which then flattens to [0,1,2,3,4,6]
```

Here's what I'm currently going after:

```
def get_list(matrix, stop_index):
    temp = [] 

    for i in range(0, stop_index):
        for m in matrix:
            temp.append(matrix[0:stop_index])
        outside_list.append(temp)

    return outside_list
```

I believe I am seeing well my over reliance on packages and libraries, so **I am really trying to do this without outside packages or imports**

Thank you for any help! I don't forget to green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension

```
l = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
ll = [ x[:len(l)-l.index(x)] for x in l]
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [6]]
print([x for y in ll for x in y ])
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Simpler syntax:

```
    matrix = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
    outside_list = list()
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        # matrix[i] is used to access very sublist in the matrix, 
        #[:3-i] is to slice every sublist from the beginning to (3 - current position)
        outside_list.append(matrix[i][:3-i])
    print(outside_list)
```

Some useful refernces

- List slicing https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8692977
- List comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835952/8692977

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I want it to but it's difficult to understand how.